# Rails 5: Get image in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to get images from my images folder into my controller (storing it in a variable), but I can only seem to find image_tag and others like it which I believe are meant for the html.erb files.  Is there a way to do the same for the controller? What is the syntax for it?

Comment: use `File`, `Dir` or `FileUtils` class. just search for how to use them.

Comment: When I do @images = Dir.glob("app/assets/images/*"), it doesn't work

Comment: @image = File.open('image_path').read

Comment: what are you trying to do? are you just trying to list the files? or are you processing the images?  share your exact code and we will be able to help better.

Comment: @jvnill I'm just trying to store images (from my images folder) in the @ images variable in my controller